# keep message count offline discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bot that counts when the nword is said, but when the bot goes offline the count resets

here is my code(the nword is being censored)

```py
bot.softn = 0
bot.hardn = 0

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.author
    if message.content == "nibba":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="racist", description=f"{user} said the N-word! \n racist!", color=0xb1f1c0)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        bot.softn += 1
    elif message.content == "nibberr":
          embed=discord.Embed(title="racist", description=f"{user} said the N-word! \n racist!", color=0xb1f1c0)
          await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
          bot.softn += 1
          bot.hardn += 1
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def racist(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Rascist Counter", description=f"N-word has been said {ctx.bot.softn} times!\n\nand of which the hard-R has been said {ctx.bot.hardn} times", color=0xefe0b4)
    embed.add_field(name="Conclusion", value="The n-word is overrated. Get a better vocabulary", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

how can I have the counter not be reset?

Comment: Save it in a file, it's logic that it resets.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I'm sorry but I'm a bit new to this, how would I do that? Can you explain in an answer form?

Comment: No, StackOverflow is not a "code it for me" type of site, you have to make an honest attempt to solve the issue no matter how easy it is, I suggest you take a look at some tutorials online, like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

Comment: A little tip: You need 2 functions. A function that `saves` and `loades` the file, as Łukasz Kwieciński suggested. Use the `on_message` event to first load and then save the counter of the words.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński you are correct, StackOverflow isn't a "code it for me" website, it is a site where you learn whether that be giving guidelines of where to find information to help figure out the answer or showing an answer and stating why you did it but a comment like  "it's logic" isn't helping or teaching me anything or anyone anything, I'm glad you linked a page to help but that was only after I responded to you. if your comment isn't helping don't post it at all cuz there no point in it

Comment: Yes, maybe I was too harsh, sorry for that. But StackOverflow should be the [last step](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in your process in finding an answer, a quick google search would help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pretty good solution based on different contributions here, so you should take a closer look next time. You have to save the counter in a file, otherwise it will be lost, no matter what you do.

You mainly need ***2 functions***:

```py
def load_counters():
    with open('counter.json', 'r') as f: 
        counters = json.load(f)
    return counters


def save_counters(counters):
    with open('counter.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(counters, f)
```

We use a JSON file called `counter` in this case. Here we `load` and `save` the JSON as a file.
`dump` means that we update the counter itself.

If you now want to listen to all the messages and save your word in this file you can use the following `on_message` event:

```py
@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
    if "YourWord" in message.content:
        counters = load_counters() # First load the file
        counters["YourWord"] += 1 # Count up
        save_counters(counters) # Save the count
```

*How do we now get the count out of the file?*

To read out the file we first have to `open` it, before we use it in a command:

```py
with open('counter.json', 'r') as f:
    counters1 = json.load(f) # Open and load the file
```

Now we can use `counter1` to display the counter with:

```py
f"{counters1['YourWord']}"
```

***I would suggest to read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) again and also have a look at how to [use JSON files in Python](https://realpython.com/python-json/)***